# Positioning transformed divs (Trigonometric solution)

Tags: javascript, css, math

I am trying to position some diamond divs using some trigonometry in javascript but it seems my logic fails somewhere.

You can see that I tried this formula: pos + trig * dimension. I hoped it would give me the right coordinates so that I can construct my diamond grid. So my question is, how can I align the diamond borders with trigonometry?

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var x1 = div[0].offsetTop + Math.cos(45) * div[0].offsetHeight;
var y1 = div[0].offsetLeft + Math.sin(45) * div[0].offsetWidth;

div[1].style.top = y1 + 'px';
div[1].style.left = x1 + 'px';
```

The entire jsfiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/

**Edit:** My intended result is this: https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/5/

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098667/1503476

Comment: @Horen I tried something new https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/7/ but my calculation seems off by a few px, why?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `.offsetHeight` , `.offsetWidth` from calculations

```
var x1 = div[0].offsetTop + (Math.cos(45));
var y1 = div[0].offsetLeft + (Math.sin(45));
div[1].style.top = Math.round(y1) + 'px';
div[1].style.left = Math.round(x1) - 9 + 'px';
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/2/

Comment: Im trying to get a alignment similar to http://www.winterbrose.com/products/software/Grid-Maker/pix/GMv1_Diamond1_160.png

Comment: Elements should be adjacent to each other ? With right side of left element touching left side of right element ?

Comment: Yes, adjacent to eachother where the bottom right border of div 1 touches  the top left border of div 2

Comment: @Asperger Try swapping `x1` to `top` , `y1` to `left` , adding `-130` to `left` before `"px"` https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/3/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137152/looping-using-position-absolute-to-form-9-boxes/ . Try setting `transform:rotate(45deg)` at `css` at http://jsfiddle.net/k554x7vs/6/ , e.g.; http://jsfiddle.net/k554x7vs/8/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/5/ doesnt resolve the question because I still have to tweak the numbers manually (20, 275). I just need to find out how to get that same position with the trig functions.

Comment: I think it does, check it out https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/8/ what do you say`? any tips for improvement? I know this can be done with trigonometry though which is what my question was actually about. If you can find a way i would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: No tips, the `1/2` is simpler than subtracting `4.5` https://jsfiddle.net/hmfxmvvs/9/

Comment: Also it does seem to be more exact too.

Comment: If your requirement is for a trigonometric solution, you should probably specify that at original Question. Or, post and accept your own solution to current Question and include requirement for a trigonometric solution at another Question

Comment: Edited my question : )

Comment: You might also consider including `math` and `css` tags at Question and specify "Trigonometric _solution_"

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips!